# create a ANN with more than one neuron output

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I start to learn artificial neural network and all introduction that I have found on internet present architecture with a number of input variable, so the input layer has the same number of "neurons" as number of variable. Then a number of neurons in hidden layers and only one output neurons.

Does it make sense to have several output neurons ? Is it the same method but with more neurons at the end ?

I have try to do some tests in fortran90, starting from a basic example, but I start to get confused to make it with more than one output neurons

Thanks

**EDIT**

To be more clear : is there a way to create an ANN with various output neurons that can take different states ? (without making a correspondence between K class corresponding to each possible output)

I would like to have 3 output neurons that will take the following states :

```
Inputs X  |  Outputs Y
----------------------
0 0 0 1 0 |   0 0 0
1 0 0 1 1 |   1 1 0
1 1 0 1 1 |   0 1 1
1 0 0 0 1 |   1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 |   1 0 0
```

if yes what is the methods ?

Comment: When you say "one output neuron", do you really mean one *output*, or one *cost*? Most introductions to neural net use multiple output but only one cost. For example, the first figure on the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network) has two output neurons.

Comment: yes that what I want like in this figure, but things are unclear for me for this last layer (output), I did a small algorithm in fortran90 with 9 input (0/1), one hidden layer, and one output, it work well, but for more output it does not at all....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to have more than one neuron in the output. The  [softmax function](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/supervised/SoftmaxRegression/) is used for that purpose. With this function, the output may have $K$ classes. If we have a network with $K = 3$ output classes, and some input shall belong to class $k = 1$, for example, the desired output would be: $[1 0 0]$. If another input shall belong to class $k = 2$, then the desired output would be $[0 1 0]$. And so on.

Comment: thanks a lot it help, my problem is not a classification problem, I would like to have directly the output state (see EDIT in my post)

Comment: In some sense it is still classification - just with multiple labels (multilabel classification). [101] e.g. says that the example belongs to classes 0 and 2. Binary cross entropy would then be more appropriate than categorical cross entropy (Softmax) though.